# How to create a slider with carousel/thumbnails in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, flexslider

I have got images in my content type and i want to show them in node type.

I've tried to use flexslider, but it doesn't format it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUFk3.png

When i try to use field slideshow module, i had result like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3CT5.png
So, i cannot choose carousel skin. Files path is /sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/skins

Guys, how i can make a slider with thumbnails in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try  this module [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need drupal module for everything - a lot of stuff you can do on your own by using custom content types and 3rd party JS libraries:

- Define content type, as you did, to hold data and make page editable.
- Create new content type for page displaying effect.
- Find some JS library (don't have to be drupal related) doing your effect
- Create template file for your second content type
- Copy HTML from that JS library example page inside your template file
- Include necessary JS and CSS file - make it work static first.
- Create some view to get effect data from your original content type
- Use views_get_view_results() to get effect data inside your second content type. Loop trough it and print out data you get instead of static values
- Or use views_embed_view() instead - makes no bid difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it's what you're searching for https://www.drupal.org/project/galleria